# Why does my WordPress site occasionally give a white screen after logging in which can only be resolved by clearing the cookies and cache?

Tags: php, wordpress

The white screen occasionally occurs after login, and does not occur at all when using an Incognito tab. 
After I clear my cookies and cache form the browser, it resolves the white screen and I can use the site as normal again.
Obviously, this issue doesn't occur simultaneously for all users at once, I just don't understand why cookies or caching would cause this.

I don't have any caching/cookie related plugins installed.

Comment: It would help us out a lot if you could kindly show us your code.  Otherwise we just guess and you spend hours testing our guesses.  You probably have a syntax error somewhere.  Is your error reporting turned on?

Comment: @Joseph_J What code would you recommend posting? The config file? Its a live site that customers use so the debug display is set to false. Also, if it was syntax, surely being in incognito/clearing browsing data wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You would post the login code and any code that the login script redirects to.

Comment: Self hosted? What theme?

Comment: @JeremiahStillings Hosted on Azure, and using StyleShop.

Answer (score 1):

This is the famous White Screen of Death fun:)

The jist is that it is caused by a plugin or theme.
Start by disabling plug ins one at a time. Log out then in. If no more white screen then contact that plug in's support at worpress.org. 
If you have uninstalled all plug ins and still have it... Swap the theme.

Source : [enter link description here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors)